# Cookie is set in settings, but can't fetch it's value

Tags: php, cookies

I create a cookie when I login my website, but if I use PHP to check if it is set it returns false... I can see the cookie if I go into my browsers setting and view the cookies.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
//Start the session
session_start();
$page = $_GET['page'];

//Check if session keys exist $uniqueID = sha1(session_id().$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && count($_SESSION['user']) == 4) {
    //User is logged in

} else {
    echo "No Session Set<br />";
    //Check for cookie
    if (isset($_COOKIE["keep_login"])) {
        echo "Cookie is set<br />";
        $t = split(".",$_COOKIE["keep_login"]);
        $email = $t[0];
        $validation = $t[1];

        //Cookie set, check it's not been moved
        include "dbconnect.php";
        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM users WHERE email=?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

            //Check password
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result($stored_session);
                $result->fetch();
                $conn->close();
            } else {
                printf("Error message: %s\n", $conn->error);
            }
            echo $stored_session;
        }
    } else {
        echo "No cookie set<br />"; 
    }
}
exit();
?>
```

This is what is displayed:

> No Session Set No cookie set

This is what my web browser displays about the cookie:

```
Name:   keep_login
Content:    martynleeball%40gmail.com.48409b8315b36ca90e51d23c77938997a796445b
Domain: karl.uphero.com
Path:   /php
Send For:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to Script:   Yes
Created:    Monday, 24 August 2015 at 16:30:02
Expires:    Thursday, 21 August 2025 at 16:30:03
```

Here is the code for setting the cookie:

```
//Create cookie if session ID is added to database
setcookie("keep_login",($ft_email.".".sha1(session_id().$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])),time()+(10*365*24*60*60));
```

Comment: Is the cookie set for the whole site?

Comment: How do you set the cookie? Show us that code please.

Comment: Added the code in my post

Comment: Try adding this after the time stuff in the cookie: , '/'

Comment: I think that's how to make the cookie available for the while site..

Comment: Thanks @JeremyBoard, unfortunately you got beat to adding it as the answer lol

Comment: Haha :D, sometimes I don't feel like putting a while code out with my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
setcookie("keep_login",($ft_email.".".sha1(session_id().$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])),time()+(10*365*24*60*60), "/");
```

It has set the cookies availability to the whole domain now.

**Reading Material:**

[Read the `path` part.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: @JeremyBoard lol, it said "show 1 more comment" when I was writing it, I checked it afterwards. :P

Comment: @MartynBall glad I could help.

Comment: Am I doing it correctly or in a decent way btw? Is the code alright ?

Comment: I personally would have your token outside in a variable  to make it clearer.